# REGULAR EXPRESSIONS

Tags: nsregularexpression

I have a simple data frame:

> test = { "City": ['A'], "Features":[ "Street20 - Statue of
> liberty\n-Avenue40 - Manhattan\n-street40 - Opera320"]}

I am using regular expressions to pull out certain information to be shown as follows:

Land_marks
Statue of Liberty
Manhattan
Opera320

I am trying with regular expressions, but it only returns the first value "Statue of Liberty". Could you help me out?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regular expression #

```
(?<=\"Features\":\[\ ").*?(?=\])
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/HUVQoj/1

Why you are using regular expression to get data from JSON? You can convert JSON to object and fetch desire result.

Comment: Thanks Pooverma! It is a dataframe that I have done by using a dictionary.